# If I delete Minecraft Pocket Edition, do I get my stuff when I download it again?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On my iPad I want to make a server.  It worked on a different WiFi.  When I got back to mine, it does not work.  So I think if I delete it, the server will be back.  Is that true?

Comment: `when I got back at mine it does not work`. As in you connected to a different network?  Is if the game or the server that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an iOS app, you also permanently delete all its data. The only thing that will remain are data stored somewhere else, such as if you had started a Realms server. If you are trying to get a wifi world back from a copy of Minecraft PE that you deleted, you're out of luck.

Comment: If the OP had iCloud Backup turned on for app data, wouldn't his saves be backed up in the cloud, and restored when he re-installs the app?

Comment: @JamesB ...maaaybe. I'm insufficiently familiar with iCloud Backup to say yea or nay. Someone who has used it to restore their MCPE worlds will hopefully chime in.